# Getting text from label tag

Tags: html, label, rating

I'm currently working on some rating stars from the value 1 to 5. If you press 3 stars you will get the message "Decent - 3/5" for example in a `<p>` tag below. How do I get the title message from the label tag and is there anyway to make the text change whenever you press another value of stars?

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="rating">
        <!-- 5 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="stars5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="stars5" title="Awesome - 5/5"></label>
        <!-- 4 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4/5"></label>
        <!-- 3 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Decent - 3/5"></label>
        <!-- 2 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Would not play again - 2/5"></label>
        <!-- 1 Star -->
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Complete garbage - 1/5"></label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Get where? With what?

Comment: Print out the title part in the <label> tag to a <p>-tag. Ex: <p>Awesome - 5/5</p>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ugly non jQuery solution. You should use IDs not "for" attributtes. And maybe you should use only one label at the end.

```
<div>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <!-- 5 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" onclick="processLabel( this );" /><label class="full" id="label5" title="Awesome - 5/5"></label>
    <!-- 4 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onclick="processLabel( this )"/><label class = "full" id="label4" title="Pretty good - 4/5"></label>
    <!-- 3 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"  onclick="processLabel( this )" /><label class = "full" id="label3" title="Decent - 3/5"></label>
    <!-- 2 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"  onclick="processLabel( this )"/><label class = "full" id="label2" title="Would not play again - 2/5"></label>
    <!-- 1 Star -->
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"  onclick="processLabel( this )" /><label class = "full" id="label1" title="Complete garbage - 1/5"></label>
</fieldset>
```

```
<script>
function processLabel( radio ) {
   resetLabels();
   var label = document.getElementById("label" + radio.getAttribute('value'))
   label.innerHTML = label.getAttribute( 'title' ) ;
}

function resetLabels() {
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("label3").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("label4").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("label5").innerHTML = "";
   }
</script>
```

Edited: Maybe I understand it wrong. There is second solution:

```
<div>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <!-- 5 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" onclick="processLabel( this );" /><label class="full" id="label5" title="Awesome - 5/5"></label>
    <!-- 4 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onclick="processLabel( this )"/><label class = "full" id="label4" title="Pretty good - 4/5"></label>
    <!-- 3 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"  onclick="processLabel( this )" /><label class = "full" id="label3" title="Decent - 3/5"></label>
    <!-- 2 Stars -->
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"  onclick="processLabel( this )"/><label class = "full" id="label2" title="Would not play again - 2/5"></label>
    <!-- 1 Star -->
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"  onclick="processLabel( this )" /><label class = "full" id="label1" title="Complete garbage - 1/5"></label>
</fieldset>
<p id="labelTitle">

</p>
```

```
<script>
function processLabel( radio ) {
   var label = document.getElementById("label" + radio.getAttribute('value'))
   document.getElementById("labelTitle").innerHTML = label.getAttribute( 'title' ) ;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example:

```
  <div>
    <fieldset class="rating">
        <!-- 5 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="stars5" name="rating" value="5" onclick="processLabel( this );" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5/5"></label>
        <!-- 4 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onclick="processLabel( this )"/><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4/5"></label>
        <!-- 3 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"  onclick="processLabel( this )" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Decent - 3/5"></label>
        <!-- 2 Stars -->
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"  onclick="processLabel( this )"/><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Would not play again - 2/5"></label>
        <!-- 1 Star -->
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"  onclick="processLabel( this )" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Complete garbage - 1/5"></label>
    </fieldset>
   </div>

<script>
    function processLabel( radio ) {
       var label = $( '[for=star' + radio.value + ']');
       label.html( $( label ).attr( 'title' ) );
       //label.html( '<p>' + $( label ).attr( 'title' ) + '</p>');
    }
</script>
```

But why are you using atribute called for? And not id? If you use id is a easy and better way.